# Dynamically show/hide part of QTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

In `pyqt4` I use QTextEdit to show some log entries. The log output is HTML like this:

```
<div class="error">Error time and message</div>
<div class="warning">Warning time and message</div>
Some unclassified test always visible.
```

I want to be able to dynamically change the visibility of each log level, identified by a div with a specified class. I.e. how can I make all divs with class *warning* disappear without manually modifying the content of the document?

Answer (score 2):

A `QTextDocument` as internally used by `QTextEdit` contains `QTextBlock` objects, which have a `setVisible()` method. Try to put the `<div></div>` sections into separate text blocks (if they aren't already; I can remember that each `<p></p>` was already assigned its own block), find them by `QTextDocument::findBlock()` or similar methods and toggle the visibility.

To change the block's visibility you probably need to parse the incoming content once, build a document with either using `QTextBlock::setUserData()` to set a hint for the class to each block, or storing sets of the block indexes depending on the class. Then you set the document as content of the edit widget and loop through all the blocks to set the visibility when the view mode changes.

Comment: How would you identify the *class* of the blocks, though? The blocks contain text, not html.

Comment: @ekhumoro Do you need to? If the text has a fixed format as the OP's example you could use the block index; no need to extract the class. Alternatively you could use `QTextBlock::setUserData()` while building the document. Of course this is not a HTML-ish solution but a Qt-ish, but I doubt this can be solved using HTML/CSS.

Comment: It seems unlikely that error log output would have a fixed order - but sure, you could use indexing if it did. But maybe the OP doesn't even have control of the output (say, because it's coming from an external source). That might explain the restriction on modifying the content of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try whether `QTextEdit` accepts class definitions like :

```
.warning {
    text-color: transparent;
    text-size: 0;
}
```

or similar.

You may be able to create the `warning` class as being invisible and very small or even zero size !? Or to set the height of the div to 0 !?

You may need to modify this class definition as needed and prepend to the test and reset it in the `QTextEdit`.

Don't know whether this actually works but it's the only way I can think of.